# using replace() to replace the dollar sing '$' from a string

Tags: javascript, string, replace

Firstly see below code:

```
var givenString = 'This is  a $ample $tring to be $ome Random $egment$ in $ociety'
console.log(givenString.replace(/$/g,"S")
```

This won't throw an output as expected i.e `This is a Sample String to be Some Random SegmentS in Society`

I tried placing the pattern in variable to run it but didn't worked.

```
var givenString = 'THis is a $ample $tring'
var pattern = /$/g
console.log(givenString.replace(pattern,"S")
```

the replace function works for any other functions but won't work for $ sign and How can I replace it with replace function?

Comment: `/\$/g`, you have to escape the character

Comment: In modern JS you could also use `replaceAll('$', 'S')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [replaceAll](https://caniuse.com/?search=replaceAll) or [escape the special character](https://javascript.info/regexp-escaping)

1 - replaceAll

```js
givenString.replaceAll('$', '*')
```

2 - escaping regex

```js
var givenString = 'THis is a $ample $tring'
var pattern = /\$/g
console.log(givenString.replace(pattern,"S")
```